# Dart Flutter Union String types

Tags: typescript, flutter, dart

In typescript if I want to make sure a variable is 'this' or 'that' I would do:

```js
type ThisThat = 'this'|'that'
```

I could then use this type in another interface like :

```js
interface B{
   text: ThisThat;
}
```

How would I do this same thing in dart/flutter using classes?  Or is there a different way to do it?  I looked up dart enums and it seems that using String enums in dart isn't exactly straight-forward.

Comment: Well, I would use a enum for that and make a method to parse the string into a enum value. You can then throw an exception if the string is not valid. Yes, it is not that smooth a solution as typescript but it is what is possible for now. There are some work being done in this area but it is to early to say if or when this feature comes to Dart.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  Would you be able to show what you mean in code?

Answer (score 6):

Since 2022, enums are easy to use as string

```dart
enum MyEnum{ first, second }

print(MyEnum.first); // it will print "MyEnum.first"
print(MyEnum.first.name); // it will print "first"

MyEnum e = MyEnum.values.byName("first"); // create from string
```

Answer (score 2):

Dart does not have such a feature yet. There has been some discussions about it but I can't remember if the feature are still considered or when it comes.

So for now we need to do what the language provides and make our own "solution". In my experience, what people most want is actually enums since the string value itself are not important after it is mapped.

Enums are also what comes closest to union string types since we have a finite amount of allowed stings which the compiler can verify we takes care of in e.g. switch-statements.

So we can do something like this if we want to make it a little fancy:

```
enum ThisThat { THIS, THAT }

ThisThat parseThisThat(String value) => ThisThat.values.firstWhere(
    (element) => element.toString() == 'ThisThat.${value.toUpperCase()}');

extension ThisThatValue on ThisThat {
  String get stringValue => toString().split('.')[1].toLowerCase();
}

void main() {
  ThisThat tt = parseThisThat('this');
  print(tt.stringValue); // this

  tt = parseThisThat('sheep'); // Unhandled exception: Bad state: No element
}
```

Personally, I would properly make it more explicit the parsing if the amount of allowed values are limited which also makes it easy to throw you own type of exception:

```
ThisThat parseThisThat(String value) {
  if (value == 'this') {
    return ThisThat.THIS;
  } else if (value == 'that') {
    return ThisThat.THAT;
  } else {
    throw Exception('$value is not a valid string value for ThisThat');
  }
}
```

Or using switch:

```
ThisThat parseThisThat(String value) {
  switch (value) {
    case 'this':
      return ThisThat.THIS;
    case 'that':
      return ThisThat.THAT;
    default:
      throw Exception('$value is not a valid string value for ThisThat');
  }
}
```

The purpose of the `extension` is so we can get the string value again. In Dart, the `toString()` on a enum value will e.g. return `ThisThat.THIS`. This is properly fine in most cases but if you want to convert it back you can add the extension method which in this case gives a `stringValue` property on the enum value.

(Should also note that it could be easier if the allowed string was not `this` since you cannot have a enum value with the name `this` since `this` is a keyword. But `THIS` is allowed so that is why my enum was upper cased. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to achieve a similar result by the means of the package [`union`](https://pub.dev/packages/union):

```
import 'package:union/union.dart';

Union2<int, String> union2 = 1.asFirst();
Union3<int, String, double> union3 = 2.asFirst();
```

Comment: I also thought first he was talking about union types but he wants to define a type which is String but only be a specific amount of values. So it is not about the need of bundling of multiple values into one. :)